# How to extract a list of all 18 character entries after specific phrase in string using RegExr?

Tags: emoji, surrogate-pairs, regex-recursion

I managed to extract a list of the text within square brackets within an emoji list I have here:

[https://regexr.com/3sqk1](http://regexr.com/3sqk1)

But now I need to extract the equivalent decimalSurrogateHtml pairs for each emoji (I know a few of them have 2 pairs but would be fine just to extract the first pair to the right of the following text)

```
"decimalSurrogateHtml":"&#55357;&#56899;",
```

I'm looking to extract just the 18 characters to the right of "decimalSurrogateHtml":

Does anyone know the expression I should enter to retrieve a list of these?

Thanks

Comment: `(?<=decimalSurrogateHtml":)[^,]+`

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you so much!

Comment: so this worked? if it did i can include it as an answer

Comment: Absolutely, Onyambu. I would have done it myself but could not see how to.